# Looping through filter criteria for a column and performing analysis on visible data to copy to new sheet - VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel, filter

Effectively what I am trying to accomplish is to filter a database (all in Sheet 1) by names, which are given in column A, and then perform various data analysis on the now filtered visible data, and then copy that data to a new sheet in a given cell.

For example, filter the data in Sheet 1 by the name 'Smith' in column A and then let's say sum all of the visible data in column B and print that to cell C3 on Sheet 2. The more advanced data analysis I am sure I can tackle on my own, just want to get rolling here and I am definitely new to VBA macro coding. I have created all of these databases using Python.

The last piece of this, would be being able to loop through all of the filter criteria in column A (which I will not know before-hand and may be anywhere from 10-20 names.

Here is the code I am working with (there are likely some syntax errors in here as well):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Data()

    Dim playername As String
    Dim team As String
    Dim numFilters As Integer
    Dim hits As Integer
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim tgt As Worksheet
    Dim filterRange As Range
    Dim copyRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    team = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name
    numFilters = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters.Count ' I want this to capture the num of filter criteria for column A

    For i = 1 To numFilters

        playername = Sheets(team).Filter(i) ' This would be the filter criteria for the given iteration
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AN$5000").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=playername

        ' Create new sheet with name of person
        Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
        ActiveSheet.Select
        ActiveSheet.Name = playername
        Set tgt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i + 1)

        ' Perform data analysis (e.g. sum column B of filtered data)
        src.AutoFilterMode = False

        ' Find the last row with data in column A
        lastRow = src.Range("A" & src.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        ' The range that we are auto-filtering (all columns)
        Set filterRange = src.Range("A1:AN" & lastRow)

        ' Set the range to start in row 2 to prevent copying the header
        Set copyRange = src.Range("B2:B" & lastRow)

        ' Copy the sum of column B to our target cell on the sheet corresponding to this iteration
        Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)).Copy tgt.Range("A1")

    Next i

End Sub
```

This is currently failing on the Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum line with the error 'Invalid qualifier'. Thanks for any help and please let me know if something needs clarified.

Comment: You can directly display value to target range instead of copy-paste "tgt.Range("A1") =Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))" and it seems you have missed to assign worksheet for variable-src

Comment: Thanks! Are you able to provide me some guidance on how to capture the number of filter criteria for a given column? And also regarding my method for looping through those criteria?

Comment: Check this link, it might help you- https://www.exceltip.com/general-topics-in-vba/display-autofilter-criteria-after-filtering-using-vba-in-microsoft-excel.html

Comment: I want to be able to specify the filter criteria prior to actually filtering though